# Fake MongoDB collection with FakeItEasy in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, nunit, fakeiteasy

I'm trying to write unit tests for my .NET Core API's service layer with NUnit and FakeItEasy and I have troubles with faking the connection to Mongo. The service is from the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mongo-app?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) with small changes.

Here is my code:

*IBaseService.cs*

```
public interface IBaseService<T>
{
    public IMongoClient MongoClient { get; }
    public IMongoDatabase MongoDb { get; }
    public IMongoCollection<T> GetCollection();
}
```

*IBoxService.cs* defines some functions

```
public interface IBoxService : IBaseService<Box>
```

*BoxService.cs*

```
public class BoxService : IBoxService
{
    private readonly IOptions<DbSettings> _dbSettings;
    private readonly IMongoCollection<Box> _boxCollection;

    public BoxService(IOptions<DbSettings> dbSettings)
    {
        _dbSettings = dbSettings;
        MongoClient = new MongoClient(_dbSettings.Value.ConnectionString);

        MongoDb = MongoClient.GetDatabase(_dbSettings.Value.DatabaseName);

        _boxCollection = GetCollection();
    }

    public IMongoClient MongoClient { get; }
    public IMongoDatabase MongoDb { get; }
    public IMongoCollection<Box> GetCollection()
    {
        return MongoDb.GetCollection<Box>(_dbSettings.Value.BoxCollectionName);
    }

    public async Task<List<Box>> FindAllAsync() =>
        await _boxCollection.Find(_ => true).ToListAsync();
}
```

*DbSettings.cs*

```
public class DbSettings
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = null!;
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; } = null!;
    public string BoxCollectionName { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

And finally the *BoxServiceTest.cs*

```
public class BoxServiceTest
{
    private readonly IOptions<DbSettings> _fakeOptions;
    private readonly IMongoClient _mongoClient;
    private readonly IMongoDatabase _mongoDb;
    private readonly IMongoCollection<Box> _boxCollection;
    private readonly List<Box> _boxes;

    public BoxServiceTest()
    {
        _boxCollection = A.Fake<IMongoCollection<Box>>();
        _fakeOptions = A.Fake<IOptions<DbSettings>>();
        _mongoClient = A.Fake<MongoClient>();
        _mongoDb = A.Fake<IMongoDatabase>();
        
        _boxes = new List<Box> {...};
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task FindAllAsync_ReturnsAllBoxes()
    {
        // Arrange
        var dbSettings = new DbSettings
        {
            ConnectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017",
            DatabaseName = "database",
            BoxCollectionName = "boxes"
        };
        A.CallTo(() => _fakeOptions.Value).Returns(dbSettings);
        
        var boxService = new BoxService(_fakeOptions);

        // Act
        var boxes = await boxService.FindAllAsync();

        // Assert
    }
}
```

Here the boxes contains the records from Mongo but I'd like it to have the values from the _boxes list instead of querying the db for every test.

I've tried faking some calls but without any success. Trying to fake the GetDatabase call:

```
A.CallTo(() => _mongoClient.GetDatabase(A<string>._, default)).Returns(_mongoDb);
```

But it gives an error:

> The current proxy generator can not intercept the method MongoDB.Driver.IMongoClient.GetDatabase(System.String name, MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabaseSettings settings) for the following reason:
> - Non-virtual members can not be intercepted. Only interface members and virtual, overriding, and abstract members can be intercepted.

What am I doing wrong? How should I fake the Mongo connection and the returned list?

Comment: The `BoxService` creates the client instance itself, so it's not testable at the moment. You should refactor it to accept the client in constructor.

Comment: Also, unit testing side note. If `BoxService` won't contain any special logic apart from calling MongoDb driver, I'd suggest testing it using a real MongoDb.

Comment: Thanks for the response and the suggestions. The `BoxService` is just one of many services I have in my API and all of them support all CRUD operations, that's why I wouldn't like to use my real DB instead of a smaller data set.
I'll change it to receive the IMongoClient in the constructor to see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I reworked my service and decided to use FindAsync instead of find. [This](https://www.thecodebuzz.com/mongodb-driver-mocking-unit-testing-iasynccursor-async-method-part2/) article helped me with the 2nd part. Now the unit test is working and my code looks like this:

*BoxService.cs*

```
public class BoxService : IBoxService
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<Box> _boxCollection;

    public BoxService(IOptions<DbSettings> dbSettings, IMongoClient mongoClient)
    {
        var mongoDatabase = mongoClient.GetDatabase(dbSettings.Value.DatabaseName);
        _boxCollection = mongoDatabase.GetCollection<Box>(dbSettings.Value.BoxCollectionName);
    }

    public async Task<List<Box>> FindAllAsync()
    {
        var cursor = await _boxCollection.FindAsync(_ => true);
        var boxList = await cursor.ToListAsync();
        return boxList;
    }
}
```

*BoxServiceTest.cs*

```
public class BoxServiceTest
{
    private readonly IMongoCollection<Box> _boxCollection;
    private readonly List<Box> _boxes;
    private readonly IBoxService _boxService;

    public BoxServiceTest()
    {
        _boxCollection = A.Fake<IMongoCollection<Box>>();
        _boxes = new List<Box> {...};

        var mockOptions = A.Fake<IOptions<DbSettings>>();
        var mongoClient = A.Fake<IMongoClient>();
        var mongoDb = A.Fake<IMongoDatabase>();

        A.CallTo(() => mongoClient.GetDatabase(A<string>._, default)).Returns(mongoDb);
        A.CallTo(() => mongoDb.GetCollection<Box>(A<string>._, default)).Returns(_boxCollection);
        _boxService = new BoxService(mockOptions, mongoClient);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task FindAllAsync_ReturnsAllBoxes()
    {
        // Arrange
        var cursor = A.Fake<IAsyncCursor<Box>>();
        A.CallTo(() => cursor.Current).Returns(_boxes);
        A.CallTo(() => cursor.MoveNextAsync(default)).ReturnsNextFromSequence(true, false);
        A.CallTo(() => _boxCollection.FindAsync(A<FilterDefinition<Box>>._, A<FindOptions<Box, Box>>._, default))
            .Returns(cursor);

        // Act
        var boxList = await _boxService.FindAllAsync();

        // Assert
        Assert.That(boxList, Is.EqualTo(_boxes));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in `BoxServiceTest` constructor. You should mock an interface:

```cs
_mongoClient = A.Fake<IMongoClient>();
```